# How to change current text in text field from another view at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have a storyboard like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PL3o.png).

My question is how do I, when the `log` button is pressed, for example, add `"log("` to the text field in the Main View? I can easily accomplish this by opening a new view with the updated text field via segues, but I need it to keep both current views open and just update the text without showing a new view. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should read a bit about delegation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

nevertheless i set up a quick demo project for you. hope it helps:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/50cosenyi3u26s8/AAA3KtjyvimuK02OEL4BHjSKa?dl=0